# Yii order by another table CActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii

I am a bit stumped on this. Basically I have two tables:

**Page:**

- id
- name

**Points:**

- id-
- pageid
- points

I am looking to get the records from the *Page* table, and sort it by the amount of points it has in the *Points* table (the points field)

Currently I have:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Page',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>"active = 1 AND userid IN (".$ids.")",
            'order'=>"???",
        ),

        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>30,
        ),
    ));
```

I just don't know how to sort it by the *Points* table value for the relevant record
I have set up a relation for the *Page/Points* tables like so:

(in the Page model)

```
'pagepoints' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Points', 'pageid'),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Add the `pagepoints` relation to the `with` part of the query criteria
2. Reference the column you want to sort by in the `order` part of the criteria

I 've marked the lines where this happens in the code below:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Page', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'with' => array('pagepoints'),  // #1 
        'condition' => 'active = 1 AND userid IN ('.$ids.')',
        'order' => 'pagepoints.points', // #2
    ),

    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>30,
    ),
));
```

What you need to know to understand how this works is that when Yii builds the SQL query (which is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to the `Points` table), it uses the name you gave to the relation in the `Page` model (you give the definition for this, it's `pagepoints`) to alias the joined table. In other words, the query looks like:

```
SELECT ... FROM Page ... LEFT OUTER JOIN `Points` `pagepoints` ...
```

It follows that the correct specification for the sort order is `pagepoints.points`: `pagepoints` is the table alias, and `points` is the column in that table.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Page',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'with'=>array('pagepoints'),
            'condition'=>"active = 1 AND userid IN (".$ids.")",
            'order'=>"t.points DESC",
        ),

        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>30,
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: Cool, thanks to both of you. I tried both methods, i forgot to metion that both tables have the fields "userid" and "created" and I'm now getting the error "Column 'userid' in where clause is ambiguous", which I understand is because it's using the duplicate names from the two tables. Is there an easy way to fix this? Or is it easier just to rename the fields in the database?

Answer (score 0):

this is the sql you want to generate:

> select * from page inner join points
>   on page.id = points.page_id order by
>   points.points desc